# Android Rotation Animation

Tags: android, rotation

I have a triangle that I want to have rotate 120 degrees every time the user clicks on the screen. I have three rotate animations that go from 0-120, 120-240, and 240-360 degrees.

Rotate 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <rotate
        android:duration="500"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="120"
        />
</set>
```

In my MainActivity page I have:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

public class StartPage2 extends Activity {

    Animation rotate1;
    Animation rotate2;
    Animation rotate3;
    View triangle2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_page_two);

        rotate1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate1);
        rotate2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate2);
        rotate3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate3);
        triangle2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.triangle2);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            triangle2.startAnimation(rotate2);

            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: and so, what's your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

public class StartPage2 extends Activity {

    Animation rotate1;
    Animation rotate2;
    Animation rotate3;
    View triangle2;
    int currentAnimation = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_page_two);

        rotate1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate1);
        rotate2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate2);
        rotate3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate3);
        triangle2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.triangle2);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            switch(++currentAnimation){
               case 1:
                 triagnle2.startAnimation(rotate1);
                 break;
               case 2:
                 triagnle2.startAnimation(rotate2);
                 break;
               case 3:
                 currentAnimation = 0;
                 triagnle2.startAnimation(rotate3);
                 break;
            }

            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and consider using `private` in front of your variables